# Actionbar Overflow Button looks transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I dont know why but because of some reasons my overflow button in my actionbar is transparent.Are there any reasons for that and how can I fix it ? Whats the default style for it ? I dont want to download material icons from Google because I think they should be already in it.

[image]

My AppTheme style :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```